# Magento onestepcheckout change order in table

Tags: magento, payment, checkout

I ran into a small problem.
I have the onestepcheckout installed together with the afterpay module.

Everything is working fine except 1 thing.

At the table where you see your subtotal and total and such.
I want to change the order of things here.
Now it is like this:

Bedrag  € 165,00
Verzendkosten   € 5,01
BTW 21% € 29,51
Totaal  € 171,01
AfterPay servicekosten  € 1,00

Of course i want to change the afterpay service charge so that it is above the total.

does anyone how i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the order of total items from system > configuration > sales > Checkout Totals Sort Order

Every extension that implements totals should implement also the ordering value, if you don't have this then add to system.xml of that module and you can then sort this.

Comment: Thank you for helping me find this:).
Problem is that the afterpay title which i want to change is not in here since it's from an external module. Do you know how i could place that higher?

Comment: i just told you :) add the value to this methods system.xml